# Api platform show PDO::__construct(): error for [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: php, mysql, api, api-platform.com

I am running api platform 2.5 version with docker. the configuration is
php : 7.2
mysql: 8.0
symfony: 4.3

.env file for doctrine

```
       DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/test
```

when I am running

```
      php bin/console doctrine:schema:create
```

I am getting the error

```
      PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: this is question is not duplicate. I have asked for api platform

Comment: The root cause is basically the same though regardless of the platform. The issue is with how PDO is being used and how MySQL is configured. If you didn't install the database server, then speak to whoever did